# Checking for Values in a Dictionary

Tags: python, performance, list, dictionary, append

I have an idea on how to figure out this problem, but I need to optimize it with a lot of data.
I pretty much want to find all of the values in each state and keep a counter of how many times they appears.

```
courses = {}

def insertIntoDataStruct(state,job,count,dict):
    if not state in dict: #adds state to list with first job and count
        dict[state] = [[job,count]]
    else:
        dict[state].append([job,count])

insertIntoDataStruct("TX", 214, 1, courses)
insertIntoDataStruct("CA", 3124, 1, courses)
insertIntoDataStruct("TX", 21455, 1, courses)
insertIntoDataStruct("CA", 5124, 1, courses)
insertIntoDataStruct("CA", 5124, 1, courses)
```

That should output:

```
{'CA': [[3124, 1], [5124, 1], [5124, 1]], 'TX': [[214, 1], [21455, 1]]}
```

So if in CA the value 5124 gets added twice, it should output instead:

```
{'CA': [[3124, 1], [5124, 2], 'TX': [[214, 1], [21455, 1]]}
```

I can make a for loop to check each time something gets appended if the number is already inside the state, but when I get thousands of values to check against when adding each line it gets time heavy.

What is the best way to optimize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure it as a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) objects. These two dictionary subclasses will make looking up states and jobs `O(1)`, and mean that you don't have to manually check for keys in `struct` or `struct[state]` - you can just add the `count` as if it was already there.

```
>>> from collections import Counter, defaultdict
>>> def insert_into_data_struct(state, job, count, struct):
    struct[state][job] += count


>>> courses = defaultdict(Counter)
>>> insert_into_data_struct("TX", 214, 1, courses)
>>> insert_into_data_struct("CA", 3124, 1, courses)
>>> insert_into_data_struct("TX", 21455, 1, courses)
>>> insert_into_data_struct("CA", 5124, 1, courses)
>>> insert_into_data_struct("CA", 5124, 1, courses)
>>> courses
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {'CA': Counter({5124: 2, 3124: 1}), 
                                            'TX': Counter({214: 1, 21455: 1})})
```

Note that I have renamed the function for compliance with [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

---

To get the top courses in each state, use `Counter.most_common`:

```
>>> {state: count.most_common(3) for state, count in courses.items()}
{'CA': [(5124, 2), (3124, 1)], 'TX': [(214, 1), (21455, 1)]}
```

---

To do the same thing with vanilla dictionaries (`courses = {}`):

```
def insert_into_data_struct(state, job, count, struct):
    if state not in struct:
        struct[state] = {job: count}
    elif job not in struct[state]:
        struct[state][job] = count
    else:
        struct[state][job] += count
```

You'll now have to find the top three yourself, though!

Comment: how can i print only the top highest collections in each state using this method?

Comment: `Counter` has a `most_common(n)` method, so you could get e.g. the top three in each state with `{state: count.most_common(3) for state, count in courses.items()}`

Comment: Thanks @johnrsharpe

so far I have done this
count = Counter(courses)
print count but its locking up when i try to print and freezes my app

Comment: Why are you trying to create a `Counter` of `courses`? Was `courses` already a `defaultdict` at that point?

Comment: So i just figured out that the shell I have to run my code on runs 2.4 so counter and defaultdict will not work, back to finding an alternative solution :(

Comment: @AndyP well 1. I strongly suggest you upgrade to something more recent; and 2. those classes are both just dictionaries with some helpful additional functionality, you can implement this fairly easily with a `dict` of `dict`.

Comment: Thanks you helped so much! I am forced to use 2.4 for an assignment. I use 2.7 on my local machine where the collections worked.